# Add Flow for Boolean That Gets Updated

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a listener:

```
class Owner { 
    private lateinit var flow: Flow<Boolean>

    init {
        flow = callbackFlow {
        val callback = object : Listener {

            override fun onExit() {
                offer(false)
            }

            override fun onEnter() {
                offer(true)
            }
        }
        MyService.register(callback)
        awaitClose {
            //service.unregister(callback)
        }
    }

    fun getFlow(): Flow<Boolean> = flow 

}
```

So then I want that every time the callback gets called the flow gets updated and any other class observing the flow would naturally get notified. How to do this?

If I want to also set the value to `true` or `false` without the callback can I do it?

Comment: [callbackFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html)

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon This crashes with the exception: `kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ClosedSendChannelException: Channel was closed`

Comment: Like it says, it's because you keep sending values in closed channel (offer/send).  `Use awaitClose as the last statement to keep it running. awaitClose argument is called when either flow consumer cancels flow collection or when callback-based API invokes SendChannel.close manually.` also it closes when job is canceled. In awaitClose you should unregister your callback. Can you post your code?

Comment: I added the code. Thanks for helping, please take a look @DrawnRaccoon

Comment: try to uncomment `service.unregister(callback)`. And ofcourse register and unregister must be used on the same service instance. I didn't notice the difference, but I would follow the example from the link `fun getFlow(): Flow<Boolean> = callbackFlow { ... }` or `fun getFlow(service:MyService): Flow<Boolean> = callbackFlow { ... }`

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon, it looks like if I unregister then I only receive the call one time. I want to keep getting the flow updates for the entire duration of the app

Comment: This means that you somehow cancel `Job` in which you execute collect, but you shouldn't do that

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon I don't cancel it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some self-contained code that proves the basic design you have works as you expect it to. It registers two listeners, starts `MyService`, lets the listeners observe some events, cancels one listener, lets the other one keep going for a while, and then cancels everything and cleanly finishes.

Therefore, the question as you asked it doesn't actually point to any problem that needs to be solved.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.awaitClose
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.callbackFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlin.concurrent.thread

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val owner = Owner()
    val consumer1 = launch {
        owner.flow.collect {
            println("listener 1: $it")
        }
    }
    val consumer2 = launch {
        owner.flow.collect {
            println("listener 2: $it")
        }
    }
    delay(100)
    MyService.start()
    delay(600)
    println("Cancelling consumer 2")
    consumer2.cancel()
    delay(600)
    MyService.stop()
    consumer1.cancel()
}

class Owner {
    val flow = callbackFlow() {
        val callback = object : Listener {
            override fun onEnter() {
                offer(true)
            }
            override fun onExit() {
                offer(false)
            }
        }

        MyService.register(callback)
        awaitClose {
            MyService.unregister(callback)
        }
    }
}

object MyService {
    private val listeners = LinkedHashSet<Listener>()
    @Volatile
    private var keepGoing = true

    fun register(listener: Listener) {
        listeners.add(listener)
    }

    fun unregister(listener: Listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener)
    }

    fun start() = thread {
        while (keepGoing) {
            listeners.forEach {
                it.onEnter()
            }
            Thread.sleep(100)
            listeners.forEach {
                it.onExit()
            }
            Thread.sleep(200)
        }
    }

    fun stop() {
        keepGoing = false
    }
}

interface Listener {
    fun onExit()
    fun onEnter()
}
```

When I run it, this prints:

```
listener 1: true
listener 2: true
listener 1: false
listener 2: false
listener 1: true
listener 2: true
listener 1: false
listener 2: false
Cancelling consumer 2
listener 1: true
listener 1: false
listener 1: true
listener 1: false

Process finished with exit code 0
```